# Pass the whole data to the onChange in a select tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

In ReactJS, onClick event does not work in Google Chrome browser but works fine in Firefox. When I add onClick event with arrow function in **option** tag inside **select** it's not work in any situation in Google Chrome.

```
<select>
   {data.map( (item) => {                            
     return(
       <>
         <option onClick={()=>alert('Test')} value={item.name} key={item.id}>{item.name}</option>
       </>
      )
   })}
</select>
```

I actually need to call an ES6 arrow function with some parameter inside **option** tag

```
<select>
{data.map( (item) => {
  return(
     <>
      <option onClick={()=>LoadNew(item.id)} value={item.name} key={item.id}>{item.name}</option>
     </>
    )
  })}
</select>
```

This is working fine in Firefox but doesn't work in the Google Chrome browser. Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with a brute force approach. since you need to pass the id of the item to a LoadNew function

```
export default function App() {
let data = [
{ name: "Love", id: 1 },
{ name: "labs", id: 2 }
];
return (
<div className="App">
  <select
    onChange={(e) => {
      let item= data.filter((val) => val.name == e.target.value);
      LoadNew(item.id)
    }}
  >
    {data.map((item) => {
      return (
        <>
          <option value={item.name} key={item.id}>
            {item.name}
          </option>
        </>
      );
    })}
  </select>
</div>
      );
   }
```

You can get the selected value by placing an onChange event Listener on the select tag. We then filter the data to get the specific item, after we pass the item's id to the function.

Comment: In React hooks, an array object set by useState, I can't extract the value of `id` directly by `item.id` . So I alter the array object `a = item.map(a => a.id)` then extract the value `a[0]` . In this way, I solved my problem for now but I don't know if this is the correct way or not. Or is there any better way to do this? Anyway, your answer helps me a lot to solve the problem. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: good I'm able to help, only thought of this as a solution. In case you find any other solution you can share. for now , you can select as answer and upvote

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `onChange` prop to the `select` tag, and from there you can access the value.

**Update:**
If you want to access the whole data you need to use JSON.

```
<select
        onChange={(e) => {
          console.log(JSON.parse(e.target.value));
        }}
      >
        {data.map((item) => {
          return (
            <>
              <option value={JSON.stringify(item)} key={item.id}>
                {item.name}
              </option>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </select>
```

Comment: I need to send the `item.id` with the arrow function. But also the `item.name` as the value for the select tag. If I set `item.id` in value attribute for option tag then I'm not getting the `item.name`.  How can I get the `item.id` and `item.name` in this way? is this even possible?

Comment: Updated my answer please check it.  You need to use JSON.parse and JSON.stringify

Comment: kindly select as answer and upvote :)

Comment: Your solution is good for solving this problem, I tried this but in my case, I face another problem if I do it in this way. I read the `select` tag value from a function by `e.target.value` So in your way the function gets a whole object instead of just `item.name` cause you are using `value` attribute for passing the object. I need to set the `item.name` in value attributes of the `option` tag also. So it's not working for me in my case. But it could be useful for another case. I appreciate your answer.